# Автоматический исходящий звонок из Aterisk по запросу с проигрыванием файла

Tags: asterisk, телефония

Необходимо по запросу звонить на определенный внутренний номер и запускать файл с голосовым сообщением (или генерировать из текста)

Возможно ли это реализовать, если да, то как?

Comment: По запросу от куда? Можно реализовать с помощью AMI/AGI. Для воспроизведения из текста TTS

Comment: От сторонней например виндовской утилитки

Comment: Как вариант, написать какой-либо скрипт на php или bash (на чем угодно), с логикой звонка http://asterisk.ru/knowledgebase/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate и дергать его из утилиты.